# Difference between MSBuild with DeployOnBuild and Visual Studio Publish

Tags: msbuild, tfsbuild, msdeploy

I have an WCF project that if i use the Visual Studio option "Publish" gets published fine.

But if I use the MSBuild parameter DeployOnBuild it does not get published correctly. I'm getting an "Could not load type" error, and all of de dlls are there.

I using the MSBuild in a Build Definition in order to have a Continuous Integration Build.

The build parameters I'm using are:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true 
/p:DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish 
/p:MSDeployPublishMethod=RemoteAgent 
/p:MsDeployServiceUrl=http://host/msdeployagentservice 
/p:username=##### 
/p:password=****
```

My main problem with this scenario is that the build targets are the same, and the build definition actualy publishes the files, but somehow they are not the same.

Any insights ???

Comment: I actualy found out the problem. The build process copied a few dlls to a projects folder. But because the files where not checked out on the TFS they did not get published in the checkin. And since the Continuous Integration Build goes only to the TFS store, the files where not in sync.

Comment: OK well that is certainly "By Design", glad you got it working :)

Answer (score 1):

I dont like to answer my on question, but since it may help someone else is the cause of the problem.

1. One of the projects had a post-build command to copy the resulting
   dll to another project specific directory (its not a reference
   because it using dependency injection in runtime).
2. The dlls did not get checked in to TFS because they are not checkout automaticaly 
   The
3. Continuous Integration Build fetches the sources from TFS and the dlls are out of sync

The solution was to checkout the dlls before the build so that the checkin updates them